# Why my variable changes its value when I am not changing it? C

Tags: c, variables

I have to read some configuration on a file to do a project from college.
In my read function I use a struct to store the configuration but, I don't know why, one of the variables changes it's value when reading the next parameter.

```
struct client_config {
    char name[20]; // en teoria son 6 + '\0'
    char MAC[12];
    char server[20];
    int UDPport;
};

void read_software_config_file(struct client_config *config) {
    FILE * conf;
    conf = fopen(software_config_file, "r");
    if (conf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error obrir arxiu");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char word[1024];
    int i = 0;

    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    // No es la millor manera de fer-ho...
    // pero ja que suposem que el fitxer es correcte
    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    // Ens saltem les comprovacions
    strcpy(config->name, word);

    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    strcpy(config->MAC, word);
    printf("%s this is config->mac after first read \n", config->MAC);

    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    strcpy(config->server, word);
    printf("%s this is config->mac after next read \n", config->MAC);

    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    fscanf(conf, "%s", word);
    config->UDPport = atoi(word);
    fclose(conf);
}
```

OUTPUT:

89F107457A36 this is config->mac after first read (this is correct)

89F107457A36localhost this is config->mac after next read (this is not correct)

The file i'm reading is this:

```
Nom SW-01
MAC 89F107457A36
Server localhost
Server-port 2019
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `struct client_config` and if necessary all types used for its members. Probably `config->MAC` is not large enough for the data you copy with `strcpy`

Comment: Without seeing the remainder of your code, when a variable changes value and you haven't changed it -- that is the result of stack (or heap) corruption generally caused by you writing beyond the end of an array or failing to allocate for a pointer variable and then writing information to the pointer address. This overwrites adjacent variable values.

Comment: Your `MAC` field is large enough to hold 12 characters, but not a 12-character *string* - you need an extra element for the string terminator.  To store an N-character *string*, you need *at least* an N+1 sized array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like your MAC field has exactly 12 chars and no place for the trailing 0 char so that the following server is directly appended during print.

Comment: I think your analysis is right, but is this supposed to be an answer or a comment?  If the former, then the "Please also post [...]" bit has no place.  And if the latter, then it is a bit sparse.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have space for the terminating `'\0'` in the `MAC` field.

When you first copy to the `MAC` field, the `printf` finds the terminating `'\0'` in the `server` field. After copying to `server`, the characters in `server` follow immediately after the characters in `MAC` without a terminating `'\0'` in between.

You need at least

```
struct client_config{
    char name[20]; //en teoria son 6 + '\0'
    char MAC[13]; // 12 characters + '\0'
    char server[20];
    int UDPport;
};
```

You should also check that `strcpy` does not copy more than the available memory for the structure fields. Maybe use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`, but make sure the result is terminated with `'\0'`. (Read the documentation of `strncpy`.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the MAC field does not have room for the trailing `\0` character. All strings in C needs to be one character longer than the actual data.

To make the reading more secure, I'd recommend using a max length for fscanf. Like this:

```
fscanf(conf, "%12s", word);
```

Or even better, use `fgets`. It makes it easy to use a variable or constant for max length.

```
fgets(word, MAXLENGTH, conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check the **struct client_config** members size, do not forget to consider the string null terminator "\0".
- Do not forget to initialize the **struct client_config** with zeros before.